# Conditional Statement on Java7

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

Hello i just started a coding exercise on hackerrank and i am having a little challenge using scanner class with the skip function. here is what i have tried.
Objective 
In this challenge, we're getting started with conditional statements. Check out the Tutorial tab for learning materials and an instructional video!

Task

*Given an integer, perform the following conditional actions:*

- If n is odd, print Weird
- If n is even and in the inclusive range of 2 to 5, print Not Weird
- If n is even and in the inclusive range of 6 to 20, print Weird
- If n is even and greater than 20, print Not Weird
- Complete the stub code provided in your editor to print whether or
  not n is weird.

Input Format

> A single line containing a positive integer,n.

Constraints

Output Format

> Print Weird if the number is weird; otherwise, print Not Weird.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {


    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = scanner.nextInt();

        if (N % 2 == 0 && N >= 2 && N <= 5 && N > 20) {
            System.out.println("not weird");

        } else if (N % 2 == 0 && N >= 6 && N <= 20) {
            System.out.println("weird");
        } else {
            System.out.println("weird");
        }

        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");


        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Please what am i doing wrong.

Comment: `N <= 5 && N > 20` <- How can N be both smaller or equal to 5 AND bigger than 20 at the same time? This condition is impossible to fulfill

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that now but still didn't work I think I need a few or one line conditional statement to run this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up `&&` and `||`, so your first `if` will never run as mentioned in the comments.

So it looks like the only `"Not Weird"` print out is `2`, `4` and even numbers `> 20`.

So use this to your advantage to just check for the `"Weird"` outputs, otherwise print `"Not Weird"`.

```
if (n % 2 == 0) {
    if ((n >= 2 && n <= 5) || (n > 20)) {
        return "Not Weird";
    }
}
return "Weird";
```

**[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/yYimI3)**

Having said this, I'm not sure what you want with [`Scanner::skip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#skip(java.lang.String))

Comment: Thanks but I am not willing to loop through I just needed to print out the result on keying in any number.

Comment: @tundeadeniyi I just gave an example of the output for a small range of numbers. Just replace the `return` statements with your `System.out.println...` and it will print the result from whatever input you provide.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (N % 2 == 0 && N >= 2 && N <= 5) {
    System.out.println("Not Weird");

} else if (N % 2 == 0 && N > 20) {
    System.out.println("Not Weird");
        
} else {
    System.out.println("Weird");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I simplified it.

```
    if(N % 2 == 0 )
    {            
        if((N >= 2 && N <= 5) || N > 20)
        {
            System.out.println("Not Weird");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Weird");
        }    
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Weird");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {
    
    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
     
        if (n%2==0 && n>2 && n<5 || n>20) {
            System.out.println("Not Weird");
        } else if( n>6 || n<20) {
            System.out.println("Weird");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Weird");
        }
    
        scanner.close();
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {


private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

    if (N % 2 == 0 && N >= 2 && N <= 5 ) {
        System.out.println("Not Weird");

    } else if (N % 2 == 0 && N >= 6 && N<=20) {
        System.out.println("Weird");
    } else if(N%2==0 && N>20) {
        System.out.println("Not Weird");
    }else {
            System.out.println("Weird");
             }        


    scanner.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
package hudai;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Hudai {   
private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

    scanner.close();
    if(N%2 == 1){
       System.out.println("Weird"); 
    } 
    if(N%2==0 && 2<N && N<5){
       System.out.println("Not Weird");
    }
    if(N%2==0 && 6<N && N<=20){
       System.out.println("Weird"); 
    }
    if(N%2==0 && 20<N && N<=100){
       System.out.println("Not Weird"); 
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
   if(N % 2 == 0){
        if((N >=2 && N <= 5) || (N > 20)){
            System.out.println("Not Weird");
        }
        else if(N >= 6 && N <= 20){
            System.out.println("Weird");
        }   
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Weird");
    }
```

Comment: _What does this code do?_ Read [answer] and [edit] your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        if (n % 2 == 1) {
            System.out.println("Weird");
        }
        if (n % 2 == 0 && 2 < n && n < 5) {
            System.out.println("Not Weird");
        }
        if (n % 2 == 0 && 6 < n && n <= 20) {
            System.out.println("Weird");
        }
        if (n % 2 == 0 && 20 < n && n <= 100) {
            System.out.println("Not Weird");

            scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You're answering an old question. Please read existing answer before posting yours. Your answer is already included [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64030302/6670491). And a code only answer is not a answer. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {



    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = scanner.nextInt();
      
        if (N % 2 == 0 && (N >= 2 && N <= 5) )
        {
            System.out.println("Not Weird");
        } 
        else if(N % 2==0 && N > 20)
        {
          System.out.println("Not Weird");  
        }
       else if ((N % 2 == 0) && (N >= 6 && N <= 20)) {
            System.out.println("Weird");
        } 
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Weird");
        }
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Answers should be more than pure code, explaining the reasoning behind the recommendations. For example, the person in this question is misunderstanding `||` and `&&`, so an explanation about those is warranted.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {



    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = scanner.nextInt();
       
         if (N % 2 == 0 && N >= 2 && N <= 5 ) {
            System.out.println("Not Weird");

        }
        
        else if(N % 2 == 0 && N>20){
            System.out.println("Not Weird");
        }
        
         else if (N % 2 == 0 && N >= 6 && N <= 20) {
            System.out.println("Weird");
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("Weird");
        }

        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using ternary operation,

```
String w="Weird";
String nw= "Not Weird";
String s= (N%2!=0)?w:(N%2==0 && (N>=2 && N<=5))?nw:(N%2==0 && (N>=6 && N<=20))?w:nw;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(n % 2 == 0){     
  if (n >= 2 && n <= 5 || n > 20) {
     System.out.println("Not Weird");
  }
  if (n >= 6 && n <= 20) {
     System.out.println("Weird");
  }   
} else if(n % 2 != 0){
     System.out.println("Weird");
 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

See code below

```
int N = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

if ((N % 2 == 0 && N >= 2 && N <= 5) || N > 20) {
    System.out.println("Not Weird");

} else if (N % 2 == 0 && N >= 6 && N <= 20) {
    System.out.println("Weird");
} 
else 
{
    System.out.println("Weird");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {



private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int N = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

   if(N %2 == 0){
    if((N>=2 && N<=5) || (N>20)){
        System.out.println("Not Weird");
        }
        else if (N>=6 && N<=20){
           System.out.println("Weird"); 
        }

   }
    else {
        System.out.println("Weird");
    }




    scanner.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. It's a bad practice to add only code. Please explain what is your purpose, what is not working

Answer (score -1):

Java 8 functional interface applied on Integer.

```java
int n = 24;   
Function<Integer, String> f = x -> x % 2 == 1 || (x >= 6 && x <= 20) ? "Weird" : "Not Weird"; 
System.out.println(f.apply(n));
```

Answer (score -2):

int N = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

```
    if(N%2==1 || (N>=6 && N<= 20)){
        System.out.println("Weird");
    }else{
    System.out.println ("Not Weird");
    }
    
    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/64030302/2227743 and other answers

Comment: Instead of posting an answer which merely links to another answer, please instead [flag the question](/help/privileges/flag-posts) as a duplicate.