# What is my mistake in this problem. Simple Comparison Error

Tags: java

Task 
Given an integer, n, perform the following conditional actions:

- If n is odd, print Weird
- If n is even and in the inclusive range of  2 to 5 , print Not Weird
- If n is even and in the inclusive range of 6 to 20, print Weird
- If n is even and greater than 20, print Not Weird

I have written a code but it is showing error in printing 18 and 20.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = scanner.nextInt();

        scanner.close();

        if(N%2 != 0){
        System.out.println("Weird");
        }
        else if(N%2 ==0 && N>=2||N<=5)
        {
            System.out.println("Not Weird");
        }
        else if(N%2 ==0 && N>=6||N<=20)
        {
            System.out.println("Weird");
        }
        else if(N%2 ==0 && N>20)
      {
            System.out.println("Not Weird");

      }  

    }
}
```

Comment: `&&` computes before `||` in `N%2 ==0 && N>=2||N<=5`. Read about operator precedence

Comment: Once you check that `N%2 != 0` you don't need to check if `N%2 == 0` every time

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. variable names should start with lowercase character

Comment: Use a debugger to find out what is wrong with ypur code

Comment: This must be a common problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645699/conditional-statement-on-java7/52651223

Comment: Your `||` should be `&&`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your *or* condition `||` to *and* condition `&&` to check for the range like

```
else if(N%2 == 0 && N >= 2 && N <= 5)
```

Comment: But `(N>=2 || N<=5)` is always true. Not very useful as a condition.

Comment: @khelwood oh indeed you're right - there must be `&&` and then no matter what bracket he will add